# C# Winform wont show everything

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm having a weird issue with a winform.

- C# winform modified with Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Preview
  Version 17.5.0 Preview 6.0 but made with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
- Target from .Net 4.0 to 4.8 (tried to bring it back to 4.0 with no success, the problem remain)
- Any CPU

Image **1** is before any change and the result is image **1A**. Than I add a textBox as shown in image **2** and get the image **2A** as result.

Even if you put it in full screen, the boxes in the botom are not there (not behind the DatagridView either). If I get rid of the TextBox, the problem remain.

- It is not a special Textbox
- Nothing is link to it. I just put it there and debug it. (release or debug give the same result)
- If i remove it, the problem remain. I have to take a copy of the winform without the TextBox to make it work again.

Images will be in order (1 - 1A - 2 - 2A)

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 1A]

[image: Image 2]

[image: image 2A]

Anyone have a clue why this is not behaving as it should ?

Thanks alot !

Comment: How about a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: This looks like a high DPI issue in combination with font scaling. You use something different then 100% scaling in Windows and ignored the warning in VS about it? Winforms is old technology and not really able to just work in high dpi environments.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228185/how-to-configure-an-app-to-run-correctly-on-a-machine-with-a-high-dpi-setting-e

Comment: I remember reading that Any CPU defaults to 32 bit.  So you may need to also set 64 bit.

Comment: @Ralf yes i did see this !  I will check for this.

Comment: @jdweng Since vs2019, Any CPU default is 64 bits

Comment: Form may contain older version.  Try deleting form and add again.